# iOS: How Protocols ensure class anonymity?

Tags: ios, protocols

I was going through the [Apple's Dcoumentation for Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) and got stuck to understand hoe protocols ensure class anonymity.

Can someone provide some code to understand how this is implemented. ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can imaging a protocol as a contract: any class conforming the protocols promises to implement this contract — the rest of the class is out of scope of this contract. It doesn't matter, what else the class is, if it subclasses a certain class or implements other protocols.

So anonymity here describes that during compile time the class of an object is irrelevant. It only needs to fulfill the contract. As Objective-C also supports runtime manipulation this applies for run time as-well.